# How to launch Chrome browser instead of Chromium in Taiko

Tags: taiko

How to launch a Chrome browser instead of Chromium in Taiko? I am unable to launch Chrome or another Chromium-based browser.

Comment: feel free to discuss [here](https://spectrum.chat/taiko)

Answer (score 2):

You can install chrome (or any chromium based browser), and these environment variables :

`TAIKO_BROWSER_PATH` - set this to the location of the browser executable (in this case chrome's path)

Additionally, you may set `TAIKO_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD` to speed up taiko install, if you do not plan to use the bundled chromium.

ref: https://docs.taiko.dev/#taiko-env-variables

Answer (score 0):

In windows command prompt, you can use like:

1. set TAIKO_BROWSER_PATH=/path/to/chrome.exe
2. taiko

When taiko is launched, it will display the path of the browser.
One more thing, each time you open a new cmd prompt, you need to set the TAIKO_BROWSER_PATH env variable. Or you need to set it permanently in windows global env variables.